# spring-data-mongodb : Check if a field is null or not exists in project filter stage

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have this stage in my aggregation pipeline, where I'm filtering the array elements where termination date is either null or doesn't exist.

```
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": 1,
        "versions": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$versions",
                "as": "v",
                "cond": {
                    "$lte": [
                        "$$v.terminationDate", null
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine in Mongo shell.
[MongoPlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GIBRJd_u1ae)

But, I'm not sure how to write this in spring-data-mongodb.

```
Aggregation.project()
    .andInclude("name")
    .and(Filter.filter("versions")
        .as("v")
        .by(ComparisonOperators.valueOf("$$v.terminationDate").lessThanEqualToValue(null)))
    .as("versions");
```

But, lessThanEqualToValue doesn't accept null.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could works. The goal is to reproduce [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JdB6O7Zjccy) using [$ifNull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) so you can try something like this:

Updated with the small change from the comments to works perfectly:

```java
Aggregation.project()
    .andInclude("name")
    .and(Filter.filter("versions")
        .as("v")
        .by(ComparisonOperators.valueOf(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("$$v.terminationDate")
                .then(true)).equalToValue(true))
    .as("versions");
```

Comment: Had to make a slight change. 
```.by(ComparisonOperators.valueOf(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("$$v.terminationDate").then(true)).equalToValue(true))```

Comment: Nice! By the way, does `new BsonNull()` instead of `null` in your initial query works? I've thought about that and maybe is easier. The result will be the same but maybe it works too.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about BsonNull. But, it doesn't work. The pipeline that is generated is 
```"$lte" : ["$$v.terminationDate", {}]```